# How can I add a namespace to all my .less files in a project?

Tags: css, webpack, less

I am working with two web applications in the same repository, and need a way to 'namespace' the CSS class names for each application.

I am using LESS as my style preprocessor, and and using webpack to bundle all the LESS files into a single .css file which then gets loaded into the webpage via HTML.

What I am currently doing is manually prepending every CSS class with my namespace like so:

```
// mylessfile.less
.nmsp {
  &__some-class-name {
     color: blue;
  }
}
```

this is annoying and not very maintainable.

Would something like this scale?:

```
// global.less
@my_namespace="nmsp";

// mylessfile.less
@import "global.less";
@my_namespace {
  &__some-class-name {
     color: blue;
  }
}
```

Is there a way to do this via LESS or even Webpack?

Ideally I would like to use a namespace for app1, app2, and a "common" styles namespace for all the styles that both applications share.

Answer (score 1):

SASS and LESS both support namespacing out of the box.

```
.app1-styles {
  @import (app1) url("app1.css");
}
```

Comment: I don't understand this code. Can you link to the documentation perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Webpack supports [CSS Modules](https://css-tricks.com/css-modules-part-1-need/) as a way to scope an app. Using CSS Modules gets you namespacing as well.

In your webpack config:

```
{
  test: /\.css$/,
  loader: 'style!css-loader?modules&importLoaders=1&localIdentName=[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]' 
}
```

Stuff inside the `[ ]` should be customized to your app.

Here's a [demo project repo](https://github.com/css-modules/webpack-demo)